# Can I use a custom domain name for API in Parse.com?

Tags: api, rest, parse-platform

I’ve read the Parse documentation regarding custom domain names, and I understand that I can host web content at a custom domain name.

Is it also possible to use the Parse REST API, or Cloud Functions, via a custom domain name?

Example:

https://api.myshoewarehouse.com/v1/shoes/

instead of…

https://api.parse.com/1/shoes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is not allowed by parse.com directly. The only way to do it is to configure proxy server somewhere on your machine, like [here](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2011/11/07/a-proxy-server-for-parse-com/).

Another way is to set api.myshoewarehouse.com domain record to CNAME pointing at api.parse.com. But then you need to:

1. ignore certificate check, e.g. with curl -k option, which obviously isn't safe thing
2. forget about changing URL path (e.g. /1/shoes/ can't be changed to /v1/shoes/)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I've also been considering using an API Management Service (possibly Azure's) that would serve as a proxy, and give me additional control and monitoring of usage of specific endpoints.